SQL Server JSON for many-to-many
I have the following tables (many-to-many):
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[ItemOwner], [dbo].[Items], [dbo].[Owners]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items] 
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [Name] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Owners] 
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [Name] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemOwner] 
(
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[Items]([Id]),
    [Ownerd] [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[Owners]([Id]),
    UNIQUE([ItemId], [Ownerd])
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Items] ([Name]) 
VALUES ('item 1'), ('item 2'), ('item 3');;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Owners] ([Name]) 
VALUES ('owner 1'), ('owner 2');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ItemOwner] 
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), -- the item is owned by two owners
       (2, 1), (2, 2), -- the item is owned by two owners 
       (3, 1); -- the item is owned by one owner

So if I do:
SELECT DISTINCT
    STRING_AGG([Ownerd], ', ')
FROM
    [dbo].[ItemOwner]
GROUP BY 
    [ItemId]

I get all permutations of owners. I want these permutations at the top level objects and aggregate the items to it.
How can I get a JSON in SQL Server which looks like this:
[
    {
        "owners": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "owner 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "owner 2"
            }
        ],
        "own": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "item 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "item 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "owners": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "owner 1"
            }
        ],
        "own": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]

I tried a lot of things - I have no clue how to combine a GROUP BY with an proper aggregate function. SQL Server 2019 (so no JSON_ARRAYAGG?)

What should happen if there's a (3, 2) Item/owner row too? Your logic ain't too clear

What you are looking for is a way to get distinct groups of identical owner/item sets. To do this, you need to group up not just the distinct OwnerId by the ItemId, you also need to group that by the new DistinctOwners list and get the grouped up DistinctItems.
Then you can use OPENJSON to crack that back open and join back to the parent tables.
Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support JSON_AGG yet, otherwise this would have been simpler. Instead we need to use STRING_AGG and concat the [] to it.
WITH OwnersGrouped AS (
    SELECT
      io.ItemId,
      '[' + STRING_AGG(io.OwnerId, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY io.OwnerId) + ']' AS DistinctOwners
    FROM
      dbo.ItemOwner io
    GROUP BY
      io.ItemId
),
ItemsGrouped AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      '[' + STRING_AGG(og.ItemId, ',') + ']' AS DistinctItems,
      og.DistinctOwners
    FROM
      OwnersGrouped og
    GROUP BY
      og.DistinctOwners
)
SELECT
  '[' + STRING_AGG(j.json, ', ') + ']'
FROM ItemsGrouped ig
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      (
        SELECT
          o.Id,
          o.Name
        FROM dbo.Owners o
        JOIN OPENJSON(ig.DistinctOwners) d ON CAST(d.value AS int) = o.Id
        FOR JSON PATH
      ) AS owners,
      (
        SELECT
          i.Id,
          i.Name
        FROM dbo.Items i
        JOIN OPENJSON(ig.DistinctItems) d ON CAST(d.value AS int) = i.Id
        FOR JSON PATH
      ) AS own
    FOR JSON PATH
) j(json);

db<>fiddle

Thanks a lot. The question is, if there is a way to work around to build it in an "step-by-step" way and using arrays and casts ;-)

Is there something wrong with my answer? What exactly are you saying?

The result is ok - but I was asking if there is a way without string workarounds and casts

@damike NO you did NOT ask that from what I can see here.  Please review and quote in your question where you did please if I am incorrect here.  FWIW this produces exactly what was asked in the question (without the questions verbose formatting of course; but JSON does not need that) only SLIGHT difference is "Id" vs "id"

@damike Yes there are ways to do that, involving some complex Relational Division and triangular cross-joins. I doubt that will be any faster.

@MarkSchultheiss what are you talking about?

@Charlieface I wounder that there is no "pure" SQL solution where you don't have to deal with string arrays. Whats "Relational Division and triangular cross-joins"? ;-)

You can use FOR JSON PATH like:
SELECT
(
    SELECT 
        o.Id,
        o.Name
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Owners] o
    JOIN 
        [dbo].[ItemOwner] io ON io.Ownerd = o.Id
    GROUP BY 
        o.Id, o.Name
    FOR JSON PATH
) AS owners,
(
    SELECT
        i.Id,
        i.Name
    FROM
        [dbo].[Items] i
    JOIN
        [dbo].[ItemOwner] io ON io.ItemId = i.Id
    JOIN
        [dbo].[Owners] o ON io.Ownerd = o.Id
    GROUP BY
        o.Id, o.Name, i.Id, i.Name
    FOR JSON PATH
) AS own FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER

Here are the Microsoft docs

That's not what OP wanted. OP appears to want to group distinct owner/item pairs

The feature FOR JSON PATH I know. The problem is how to get the expected result ;-) Your query gives me something different
